Can't run 4k external monitor from my laptop
I have been trying to get my 4k external monitor displaying at 4k resolution for a while. I bought it in February and since then it displayed 4k perfectly, although a few weeks ago while I was running Virtual Desktop for a VR application, it changed automatically to 1080p. So I know the laptop can display to a 4k external monitor. Looking back I probably should have disconnected my external monitor while playing VR to apply less stress on my laptop. Since then whenever I select the 4k setting in Windows display settings, or NVIDIA control panel, it automatically reverts back to 1080p. I tried to connect a different 4k external monitor (older with less contrast than new 4k external monitor that I have been using since February) and that ran fine in 4k.
The things I tried so far with no luck:
-Swapping 4k-compatible HDMI cables
-Using different HDMI ports
-Disconnecting power cable to 4k external monitor for 2 minutes then powering back on and reconnecting to laptop
-Power cycling laptop
-Running troubleshooter in 4k external monitor
-Factory resetting my 4k external monitor
-Using "extend" and "show only on" options in Windows display settings
-Selecting the 4k external monitor to only display in NVIDIA control panel
-Changing the "perform scaling on" option to both "GPU" and "display" on the NVIDIA control panel "adjust desktop size and position" tab
-Updating 4k external monitor firmware to the latest
-Trying older versions of NVIDIA and AMD firmware before the 1080p issue
-Updating all Windows, NVIDIA, and AMD firmware to the latest
My specs are below:
Laptop: ROG Strix G15 (2022) G513
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon Graphics
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
Memory: 16GB
Display: Samsung Odyssey Neo G8
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Not an answer, but do not be concerned about, "stress on my laptop," causing any issue. If stress had damaged it, the card would simply not work. Simple test: boot from USB with another OS or Windows2Go, and test 4K res. Most likely cause is a Windows setting or Registry entry, not hardware.

Ahh I see, thanks for the response. I tried to connect it to a desktop and it displayed 4k automatically. So now I know that at least I don't need to send my monitor in for repair. I think it is because it is too demanding on my laptop. Although, that is a gaming laptop and even advertised on the Asus website for the ROG Strix G15 "HDMI 2.0b lets you connect a 4K monitor or TV at up to 60Hz".

"I bought it in February and since then it displayed 4k perfectly, although a few weeks ago while I was running Virtual Desktop for a VR application, it changed automatically to 1080p." Since it worked before, it should work at 4k again. As mentioned, try booting that PC from USB, and likely it will be fine at 4k. Most likely, a Windows setting or Registry entry is the cause.

Ahh kk, thanks. The NVIDIA admins at reddit tell me that DDU fixes most driver related problems (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xRRx_3r8GgCpBAMuhT9n5kK6Zse_DYKWvjsW0rLcYQ0/edit) although I am waiting to try this after completing some things I have to do since there is a risk of damaging the OS or data loss.

That should fix the registry issues

It turns out that DDU didn't fix the issue when I tried it for the NVIDIA graphics card and the AMD integrated graphics card. I also tried a factory reset and that still didn't work. Now I am resorting to using the old 4k monitor and may end up just buying a computer to run the new monitor. I tried connecting the new monitor again to another computer and it ran 4k fine using an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPU, so the same one on my laptop basically. I think for some reason my laptop GPU isn't powerful enough to display both the laptop screen and the external monitor.
